# Simple knex query returning table name only

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I am trying to work with knex to retrieve some database values however no matter the configuration I use I am either getting a `500` error code or just a pending network session. To keep it as simple as possible to get something at least working I have written the following:

```
export default () => (async (req, res, knex) => {
    const temp = knex('vouchers').select();
    console.log(temp);

  res.response(201).end();
});
```

Which should by my understanding go into my `vouchers` table and retrieve everything, I only end up getting a `500 error`and a console log of `vouchers` i.e. my table name...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
export default () => (async (req, res, knex) => {
  const temp = await knex('vouchers');
  console.log(temp);
  res.send(JSON.stringify(temp,null,2));
});
```

Comment: Not to worry, I managed to get it working, thanks anyway have some free points.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was basically restructuring the start of the query:

```
export default function ({ pool, queue, knex }) {
  return async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      const { eventId, voucher } = req.params;
```

with special attention to the async params.